# Open a vector .TAB (MapInfo Pro) file using C# (Net6.0) and GDAL

Tags: gdal, vector, c#, mapinfo, .net

I'm trying to open a vector file using GDAL's C# bindings. However, running the below code keeps returning null instead of a Dataset for some reason for the `dataset` variable.

I've installed GDAL (v 3.6.4) and GDAL.Native (v 3.6.4). In the setup, I copied the GdalConfiguration.cs code found in `C:\..\GDALTest\obj\Debug\net6.0\NuGet\EDE15D71CD0E9DD7D895094E51A5C8004A7F1505\GDAL\3.6.4` into a new MyGdalConfiguration.cs class.

```
using GdalTest;
using OSGeo.GDAL;

MyGdalConfiguration.ConfigureGdal();
MyGdalConfiguration.ConfigureOgr();


var vectorPath = "C:\\TEMP\\test";
var vectorPath2 = "C:\\TEMP\\test\\someFile.TAB";

// i've tried a few combinations for the below params, but none worked
// Gdal.OpenEx() params: (string utf8_path, uint nOpenFlags, string[] allowed_drivers, string[] open_options, string[] sibling_files)
var dataset = Gdal.OpenEx(vectorPath, 0, null, null, null);
```

I've spent hours looking through documentation trying to figure this out, but couldn't come up with an answer. It doesn't help that there is no explicit C# documentation and the bindings don't appear to be 1:1 with the C++ docs

utf8_path should accept either a directory or a .tab file according to this: https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mitab.html. So either `vectorPath` variable should be valid.

I'm not quite sure what `nOpenFlags` or the other args are supposed to look like. I think `allowed_drivers` could be like `new string[] { "MapInfo File" }`, but if you leave it blank, it should just look through all of the drivers for a compatible one if set to null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that the input file that I was trying to use is a NativeX file.

After saving it as just a Native file, I was able to get it to run as expected (so far)

It looks like precisely has a separate driver that extends the functionality that I will need to research later: https://support.precisely.com/product-downloads/item/mapinfo-efal-sdk-download/